# Don't slideToggle all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have a vertical sliding menu, that looks like this:

```
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>link</li>
        <li>link</li>
        <li class="more">link with submenu</li>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>sub link 1</li>
                <li>sub link 2</li>  
            </ul>
        <li class="more">link with submenu</li>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>sub link 1</li>
                <li>sub link 2</li>  
            </ul>
        <li>link</li>  
        <li>link</li>

    </ul>
```

the jQuery is like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".more").click(function() {

$(this).parent().children(".submenu").slideToggle(500); });
});
```

My problem is, when I click on a ".more", every ".submenu" is being slideToggle (Both opens)

How can I do, so it is only the correct submenu that is being slidetoggled?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the call to `.parent()`. Also, your `.submenu` should be nested *within* the `<li>` to which it belongs, leaving you with the following jQuery:

```
$("li.more").on("click", function() {
    $("ul.submenu", this).slideToggle(500);
});
```

And this markup:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li class="more">
        link with submenu
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>sub link 1</li>
            <li>sub link 2</li>  
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="more">
        link with submenu
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>sub link 1</li>
            <li>sub link 2</li>  
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>link</li>  
    <li>link</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

this one?

```
$(this).next().eq(0).slideToggle(500); });
```